# Yum command ModuleNotFoundError on centos 8

Tags: centos8

I have a CentOS 8 server, and tried to install Mysql on it with following commands:

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
yum update
```

when I enter `yum update`, it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/common_types.py", line 14, in         swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: /lib64/librpmio.so.8: symbol EVP_md2 version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined     in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import dnf.base
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    import libdnf.transaction
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import common_types
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/common_types.py", line 17, in <module>
    _common_types = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/common_types.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_common_types')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_common_types'
```

My python is installed via

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.8.3.tgz
mkdir /usr/local/python3/
cd Python-3.8.3
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3
make
yum install zlib* -y
make install
ln -s /usr/local/python3/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/python3/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

It seems yum command is using the `/usr/lib/python3.6/`, which is different from the Python version I am using. How can I fix my `yum` command?